# Different citation style for websites and other items

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I would like to differentiate the citation output for website from the setting in the MWE for books, journals, etc. (which I want to maintain).

For the website and only for the website I would like the following output:

*Title*. (Year). Retrieved *date* from *URL*.

Please consider the following MWE with a bibliography of one book and one website.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{van_de_donk_cyberprotest_2004,
    address = {London},
    url = {www.jstor.com/somearticle.html},
    urldate = {2013-10-29},
    title = {Cyberprotest: {New} media, citizens, and social movements},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    editor = {van de Donk, Wim B. H. J.},
    year = {2004}
}
@misc{website,
    title = {This is a blog},
    url = {www.blog.com},
    urldate = {2013-08-29},
    journal = {Blog},
    month = feb,
    year = {2009}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Remove series & month
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearfield{series}
  \clearfield{labelmonth}
  \clearfield{edition}
}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test1} 

\cite{test2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you be OK with using `@online` as `entrytype` for the website instead of `@misc`? Or are you OK with all `@misc`s having the proposed website format?

Comment: I am OK with all `@miscs` having the proposed website format.

Comment: Try `\savebibmacro{url+urldate}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{\ifentrytype{misc}{\restorebibmacro{url+urldate}\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}{}}`

Comment: My above solution requires `url=true`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote you can do the following:

1. Use the option `url=true`
2. redefine the bibmacro `url+date` so that it will print urls only if the entrytype is `misc`

   ```
   \savebibmacro{url+urldate}
   \renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
      \ifentrytype{misc}{\restorebibmacro{url+urldate}\us‌​ebibmacro{url+urldate}}{}%
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You might like the following redefinition of the `*cite` commands (as defined in `apa.cbx`).
We just add a different treatment for `@misc` entries; the rest stays exactly the same.
Put this code into your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}%<--- from here
    {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
     \newunit
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
     \printtext{\addperiod}
    }%<----- to here is new; what follows is standard apa.cbx
    {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
  % Multiple cites in one command
     {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}%
  % Single cite
     {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
  % No author/editor
       {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
         \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
         \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
  % Normal cite
       {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
          {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}%
          {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
            {\printnames{shortauthor}}
            {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}\addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
        \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
     \setunit{\multicitedelim}}}
\makeatother
```

The MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{van_de_donk_cyberprotest_2004,
    address = {London},
    title = {Cyberprotest: {New} media, citizens, and social movements},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    editor = {van de Donk, Wim B. H. J.},
    year = {2004}
}
@misc{website,
    title = {This is a blog},
    url = {www.blog.com},
    urldate = {2013-08-29},
    journal = {Blog},
    month = feb,
    year = {2009}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Remove series & month
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearfield{series}
  \clearfield{labelmonth}
  \clearfield{edition}
}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
     \newunit
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
     \printtext{\addperiod}
    }
    {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
  % Multiple cites in one command
     {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}%
  % Single cite
     {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
  % No author/editor
       {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
         \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
         \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
  % Normal cite
       {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
          {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}%
          {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
            {\printnames{shortauthor}}
            {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}\addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
        \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
     \setunit{\multicitedelim}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\cite{van_de_donk_cyberprotest_2004} 

\cite{website}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

Comment: Great! But how do you print the extended form of the website entry also within the references? I would actually prefer to have only `'title', year` inline and the long version `title. (year). Retrieved month day, year, from source.` in the references. [see here](http://www.usq.edu.au/library/referencing/apa-referencing-guide)

Comment: @Francesco Mhhh, in that case no redefinition is needed at all, just change `url=false` in the options to `url=true`, after all you *do* want to see the URL.

Comment: But if I switch the option to `url=true` I will output the url also for all the articles that I have in my bibliography. (Sorry I notice now that this was not clear in my question, I re-edited it)